# Como criar variáveis dinamicamente (Speech_recognition)

Tags: python, python-3.x, reconhecimento-de-voz

Preciso transcrever um áudio de 21 minutos usando speech_recognition e recognize_google o problema é que a api não permite qualquer tamanho de áudio, eu não sei exatamente qual mas é maior que 30 segundos por isso criei a função:

```
with contextlib.closing(wave.open(fname, 'r')) as f:
    frames = f.getnframes()
    rate = f.getframerate()
    duration = frames / float(rate)
    splitaudio = duration / 30

blocos = int(round(splitaudio, 0) + 1)
```

Que me retorna 43 blocos.

Esse código a seguir funcionária:

```
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
     audio1 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio2 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio3 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio4 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio5 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio6 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio7 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     audio8 = r.record(source, duration=30)
     #... até atingir o valor de blocos que tenho ... #

speech1 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio1, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech2 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio2, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech3 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio3, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech4 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio4, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech5 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio5, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech6 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio6, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech7= ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio7, language='pt-br') + '\n')
speech8 = ("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio8, language='pt-br') + '\n')
#até completar

with open('frases/frases.csv', 'a') as writefile:
     writefile.write(speech1)
     writefile.write(speech2)
     writefile.write(speech3)
     writefile.write(speech4)
     writefile.write(speech5)
     writefile.write(speech6)
     writefile.write(speech7)
     #... até completar
```

No entanto eu preciso ficar criando muitas variáveis e esse código só seria útil para esse áudio, algum ideia de como melhorar esse código criando essa variáveis dinamicamente ? Ou alguma outra abordagem para não ser necessário digitar tanto e deixar o código mais limpo ?

****** EDIT ******

Nessa parte :

```
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
         audio1 = r.record(source, duration=30)
         audio2 = r.record(source, duration=30)
         ...
```

A variável audio1 grava os primeiros 30 segundos de áudio, a variável audio2 do 30 ao 60 e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Estude sobre listas do Python.

Comment: Pela pergunta, acredito que você pretende escrever em um arquivo, então escreve os valores da lista no arquivo.

Comment: Quando dentro do with : audio1 = r.record(source, duration=30)  grava os 30 primeiros segundos. audio2 = r.record(source, duration=30) grava do 30 ao 60 e assim sucessivamente por isso preciso criar essa variáveis dinamicamente, se não fosse por isso poderia simplesmente .append como você deve estar sugerindo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você sabe a quantidade de blocos, faça um laço de repetição que armazene os valores em uma lista:

```
N = 43

audios = []

with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    for _ in range(N)
         audios.append( r.record(source, duration=30) )
```

Isso evita de ter que ficar definindo uma variável para cada 30s de áudio.

Comment: Caramba, sua resposta só apareceu para mim 1 minuto apos a minha publicação, se não não teria publicado, o estranho é que aparece como lpublicada 20 minutos atras.

Comment: @Sidon Cache da página, talvez :D

Comment: Verdade, quase certeza!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi vc sabe de antemaão quantos `blocos` de `30s` serão, se for isso, uma forma de fazer isso seria, como foi sugerido, guardar em uma lista, digamos que saibamos de antemão que sejam 10 blocos:

```
audios = []
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    for n in range(0,10)
        audios.append(r.record(source, duration=30))
```